# Wanna write the log in network path using log4net

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

i am using log4net for write the log files, i am able to write in network path also my doubt is there any way that i can pass the creditials such as username and password of the network system to write the log for security purpose. Are there any API's which will support my requirement.

currently i am using like

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("COMMON_APP_DATA", string.Format(@"{0}\\ProHance Mate logs\\{1}\\Service\\service.log", @"\\JAMOCHA44\Raviknth", Environment.MachineName));
```

in app config i will set the path this way.

```
<file value="${COMMON_APP_DATA}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give the user writing the logs access to the network drive. That way you do not need to put any credentials in your application. Or log to a local drive and use a process that has access to that drive and the remote drive to copy logs.